# XML filter elements

Tags: xml, xslt

i am stuck with xsl. This is my xml file (abstract):

```
<data>
  <post>
    <Status>publish</Status>
    <Title>myTitle1</Title>
    <Content>blabla</content>
  </post>
  <post>
    <Status>publish</Status>
    <Title>aaa</Title>
    <Content>blabla</content>
  </post>
  <post>
    <Status>draft</Status>
    <Title>Title3</Title>
    <Content>blabla</content>
  </post>
</data>
```

This is my sort xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/data" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="post" >
            <xsl:sort select="translate(Title, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" order="ascending" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to remove all post elements with element Status "draft" completely and on status "publish" just the status element and then sort it ascending by title.

So the final xml should look like this:

```
<data>
      <post>
        <Title>aaa</Title>
        <Content>blabla</content>
      </post>
      <post>
        <Title>myTitle1</Title>
        <Content>blabla</content>
      </post>
</data>
```

Thanks Marc

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. XML is case-sensitive: `<Content>` does not match `</content>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="post[not(Status='draft')]" >
            <xsl:sort select="translate(Title, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::Staus)]"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```